# Como obtener resultados XML en Linq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

en Xml quiero extraer los siguientes datos con Linq

```
<tradeItemMeasurements>
-<depth>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="CM">
<value>15</value>
</measurementValue>
</depth>
-<grossWeight>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="KG">
<value>1</value>
</measurementValue>
</grossWeight>
-<height>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="CM">
<value>12</value>
</measurementValue>
</height>
-<width>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="CM">
<value>12</value>
</measurementValue>
</width>
-<netContent>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="PC">
<value>100</value>
</measurementValue>
</netContent>
-<netWeight>
-<measurementValue unitOfMeasure="KG">
<value>1</value>
</measurementValue>
</netWeight>
</tradeItemMeasurements>
```

mi query en c# es:

```
var ItemMeasurement = tradeItem.Descendants("tradeItemMeasurements").Descendants("depth").Descendants("measurementValue").ElementAt(0).Value;

Console.WriteLine("Medidas del producto: " + ItemMeasurement);
```

y me imprime solo el numero 15, osea el primer valor de CM

yo quiero que mi imprima Medidas del producto(depth): [VALOR][UNIDAD]
Medidas del producto(height): [VALOR][UNIDAD]

Y asi con todos..

alguna idea??

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que pretendes es resolverlo usando Linq, para hacerlo var a tener que usar [XContainer.Elements](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener los nodos que son hijos directos de `tradeItemMeasurements` y así, jugando un poco con el `Select` podrías crear un objeto anónimo con los datos que buscas, vease también [XElement.Attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) que es el método usado para obtener `unitOfMeasure`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XMLData);
//Uso Elements para obtener sólo los elementos de primer nivel dentro de tradeItemMeasurements
var Result = doc.Descendants("tradeItemMeasurements").Elements()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        //Almaceno unidad en una variable para evitar un loop innecesario
        var Unidad = x.Descendants("measurementValue").FirstOrDefault();
        //Devuelvo un objeto anónimo
        return new
            {
                //Dato es el tipo de medida con la propiedad Name del nodo
                Dato = x.Name,
                //Para la unidad uso la variable que definí anteriormente, y su método Attribute
                UnidadDeMedida = Unidad?.Attribute("unitOfMeasure")?.Value,
                //Por último obtengo el valor
                Valor = Unidad?.Elements("value").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
            };
    });

foreach(var element in Result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dato: {0}\nUnidad de Medida: {1}\nValor: {2}",element.Dato,element.UnidadDeMedida, element.Valor);
}
```